# Extract all tables from PDF in python

Tags: python, pdf, pdftables

I have an PDF and want to extract all tables from that PDF. When I run the code below, I get empty list.

```
import pdftables

filepath = 'File_Set_-2_feasibility_Study/140u-td005_-en-p.pdf'
with open(filepath, 'rb') as fh:
    table = pdftables.get_tables(fh)
print(table)
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/camelot-dev/camelot

Comment: @Neeraj Sharma: Try SLICEmyPDF in 1 of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017702/how-to-extract-table-from-pdf-in-python/72414309#72414309

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the PDF has more than one page? This should work:

```
from pdftables.pdf_document import PDFDocument
from pdftables.pdftables import page_to_tables

filepath = ...
page_number = ...
with open(filepath, 'rb') as file_object:
    pdf_doc = PDFDocument.from_fileobj(file_object)
    pdf_page = pdf_doc.get_page(pagenumber) 
    tables = page_to_tables(pdf_page)
    print(tables)
```

You can iterate over several pages, too:

```
for page_number, page in enumerate(pdf_doc.get_pages()):
    tables = page_to_tables(page)
    print(tables)
```

Comment: i forgot to mention i am using pyhton3, installed pdftables.six and in this package 
from pdftables.pdf_document import PDFDocument not there instead from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument is there which does not have "from_fileobj"

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? It sounds that `File_Set_-2_feasibility_Study/140u-td005_-en-p.pdf` is a absolute not relative path. Is it where the file is stored?

Comment: When i tried pdfReader just to see whether it prints all text, but surprisingly it prints everything else other than table data.

Answer (score 0):

#install below library to use pdf table, its worked for me

```
> pip install pdftables.six
```