# How to extract tables data from pdf in python?

Tags: python

I used PyPDF2, Tabula, Camelot, pdfminer libraries but I got Data alignment issues and Data loss. Is there any solution ?

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Can you give example of the issues? Please read [ask]

Comment: The Data of each Column is coming into one cell

Comment: I mean, give a [mcve]

Comment: 1,305
1,239
24,004...the values 1,305 1,239 24,004 should come in different rows in a csv but i am getting all the these 3 values in a single cell one below the another.

Comment: Show us your code: We cannot tell you what goes wrong simply based on the result

Comment: I think all packages that extract data from a pdf source are based on the pdf template. on that template, and not like DOCX files, there are no cells as far as I know... so it would be difficult to extract your data based on that sample.

Comment: import camelot
tables = camelot.read_pdf(h, pages="all")
table_count = len(tables)

for i in range(table_count):
    tables.export("pdf_test_csv", f="csv", compress=True)
    tables[i].parsing_report
    tables[i].to_csv(temp + key_string + "_" + str(i) + ".csv", index=False)

Comment: @Pavan Prayaga: Try SLICEmyPDF in 1 of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017702/how-to-extract-table-from-pdf-in-python/72414309#72414309