# How to extract data from tables in a pdf using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

I need to extract data from tables in multiple PDF's using Python. I have tested both camelot and tabula however neither of them are able to accurately get the data. The tables have some merged cells, cells with mutiple lines of information etc. so both these libraries get confused. Is there a good way of approaching this issue?

Comment: Try SLICEmyPDF in 1 of the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56017702/how-to-extract-table-from-pdf-in-python/72414309#72414309

Answer (score 1):

There may be something wrong with the underlying structure of the table encoded in the PDF if that's the case.

You could use OCR, and do some string/regex manipulation to extract column data from each row. [github.com/cseas/ocr-table](https://github.com/cseas/ocr-table) seems to work. See the [input.pdf](https://github.com/cseas/ocr-table/blob/master/input.pdf) and [output.txt](https://github.com/cseas/ocr-table/blob/master/output.txt) to see if it works with your situation.