# Fix missing header while reading table in PDF file using Tabula

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula

I want to extract tabular data from PDF file image below [Statistical Import/Export Data of year 1992 to 1993 in PDF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWrdp.png)

The data I want is the numerical data to create a data set. I have tried using tabula.py library but the data I am getting is not usable or correctable: [Tabular Data extracted by Tabula Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9bI0.png).

Code Snippet :

```
# Modules Imported
import tabula
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd

# PDF file is being read and tables are being stored in a dataframe
df = read_pdf(PDF_FILE_PATH, stream=True, pages = "all")
```

Also, another snippet of code is yielding same result even when using area and columns parameters

```
pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(PDF_FILE_PATH)

num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)
num_pages

table_pdf = read_pdf(
    PDF_FILE_PATH,
    guess = False,
    pages = 1,
    stream = True,
    encoding = 'utf-8',
    area = (0, 0, 200, 250),
    columns = None,
)
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Original file here: [PBS Govt Statistical Tabular Data](https://www.pbs.gov.pk/sites/default/files//external_trade/8_digit_level/import/1_imp_1990-91_to_1993-94.pdf)

Comment: If none of those work https://stackoverflow.com/q/56017702/12846804, have you considered working on smaller files first?

Comment: @OCa could you elaborate a little, the problem is that if I assign boundaries for a pdf document then it will only apply to that particular document and I would need to do it for all the documents.

Comment: I mean you are a new user, so we have to ask: Were you able to make Tabular work with simpler pdf files?

Comment: @OCa yes, for simpler pdf file text is extracted, problem I am facing is when when using tabula.py library the table is not formatted and some values are missing. How can I do this correctly or am I using the wrong approach. Kindly help.

Comment: I have proposed an edit to your question that will hopefully improve visibility. That will just have to wait for review. After my edit has been accpeted, please add the command line that you have used to read the pdf.

Comment: You are welcome, ok now please add the command line(s) that you have tried.

Comment: Added the code snippet, both of them.

Comment: all right, it's a good "SO" question now, upvoting. Good luck.

Comment: @OCa Many Thanks, Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have fixed pitch text like from a LinePrinter you can use ye olde methods from a Century Long Time Ago. So ever since I can remember Excel 4 ? had import MSDos text and so I usually use Office 97 for such outputs, anyway here using 2013 as it's only a decade old we can see the inputs in order.

[image]

So program wise it is very manual, one line of code and a Human Eye.

Above data frame was generated by

```
poppler\22.02>pdftotext -nopgbrk -fixed 6  imports.pdf
```

The real MacroCoding will be needed to tidy up the third column in a humane logical fashion, to handle any missing wrapping stripped on conversion.

However to remove those unwanted page headings it is best to use Modern equivalent of DOS Findstr, so to exclude page numbers and ---- we need to run a second line of code.

Let's check it works in reverse first, we want to be sure they will be excluded, and here we note that after 1005 pages there are a secondary 12 to consider.

[image]

That was good enough so pre-process data.

`findstr /v /l "IMPORTS Value \| ity ------" imports.txt > cleaner.txt`

[image]

So the text is now good for import in columns to Excel but watch out for that third column ensure it's `NO` and rightwards.

Going back to that exclude all headings (including 2 ! sets on page 1)
we would need to just export the first set first so now we want:

[image]

So the whole command set is

```
pdftotext -nopgbrk -fixed 6 -f 1 -l 1 -H 140 -W 900 imports.pdf DataFrame.txt
pdftotext -nopgbrk -fixed 6  imports.pdf -| findstr /v /l "IMPORTS Value \| ity ------" imports.txt >> DataFrame.txt
```

That's under 10 seconds to run the 2 line program

[image]

Then Python or Excel  /e or /m (with  a suitable import macro) to load DataFrame.txt

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer. This is by far more simple and easy than I what I was doing. Many Thanks Again. @k-j @K J